# Validating customer names, address and phone

Tags: php, regex, validation, prestashop-1.5

So far I have been quite impressed by out of the box features provided by Prestashop but this thing really let me down: If someone wants to register on the site or do a guest check out he can put anything as his name. Anything includes things like "---", all spaces, "***" etc. There is no validation provided here and this is really annoying.

I have tried to modify the processSubmitAccount method in website\controllers\front\AuthController.php to use the Validate::isName() method but this does not help at all. It lets the users put all the strange character in the name field. I tried to create another method inside the Validate class:

```
public static function isHumanName($name)
{    
 return preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]+$/', $name);
}
```

but for some reason this simple pattern does not work. All I want to be able to do is allow names like "FirstName MiddleName" having only one space chracter at a time and not at the start of the name. My php and regex skills are minimal and this is all I have come up with so far.

EDIT: Acceptable names would be:

1. FirstName
2. FirstName Second Third Fourth Fifth
3. Names can be case insensitive.

After reading comments, I think I will give up on validating Addresses so striking out below para.

<strike>Besides name I want to validate addresses and phone numbers. Addresses can have numbers in addition to letters while phone numbers can only have numbers. I guess if the problem with validating names is solved then I would be able to do it for address and numbers as well.</strike>

I would appreciate if someone can put me in right direction.

**PS: It is a separate debate whether enforcing a naming policy is right or wrong.**
**DISCLAIMER: The answer to this question does not mean that readers use the same thing in their production applications for validating names.**

Comment: I wouldn't, see [this](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).  The same is true for addresses.  However, you potentially could make a good enough expression to validate phone numbers (but I would stay lenient).

Comment: What about `O'Brien`?  What about names with accents or non-ASCII characters?  Basically you should just live with the fact that names might not fit a certain criteria.

Comment: Who is the down voter and why? @SamSullivan looking at the link I get the idea that we should never ever validate names? So how would I call a person whose name is --- or '''? Hello Mr triple single quotes?

Comment: @MikeBrant youre point is valid but I want to start from basic regex and then move on to something which allows O'Brien or Abd-ul-Haq but not ''''OBrien or ---Na****me---- or even just "      Name". Certainly people having such names will not be welcome unless they call to tell me how to prnounce their name atleast.

Comment: @sttaq So you best bet is to define, in plain language, what you consider to be an acceptable entry as a starting point.

Comment: @staqq I was the downvoter, for the reasons I posted.  In the end I would rather save the name `---` then reject someone for having a obscure name.  Errors are horrible for a UX, so avoid them if possible (I use the same mentality for password strength: recommend a user to improve the password, don't force them).  Anyways, what is your use case that a valid name is so critical?

Comment: @Sam I understand your point and valid name policy is not critical. I wanted to learn how I can make such regex. The policy is dictaced by employer and is implemented by myself. I can only put your suggestions forward. I can not argue. I have to implement however they want it to be.

Comment: @sttaq awesome. I'm sorry for being a little overly critical.

Comment: thanks, its all right to be critical. The point is to learn and I think you enlightened me to a perspective which I would have not thought of. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+$/', $name);
```

would match:

```
FirstName MiddleName
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/lE5gW4

**EDIT:**

Ok, this conforms more closely to what the OP is requesting.

Regex:

```
^([A-Z][A-Za-z]+) (?:([A-Z][A-Za-z.]+) )?([A-Z][A-Za-z]+)$
```

This matches the following variations..

```
FirstName M. LastName
FirstName LastName
FirstName MiddleName Lastname
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/nG1vN5

Note: and if you wanted to allow `'` in the name such as in `O'Brien` or any other characters, you could just add them into the character sets.  ie- `([A-Z][A-Za-z.']+)`

Php example:

```
$name = "FirstName M. LastName";

$truefalse = preg_match('/^([A-Z][A-Za-z]+) (?:([A-Z][A-Za-z.]+) )?([A-Z][A-Za-z]+)$/', $name);

echo $truefalse;
```

Output:

```
1
```

Working php example:

https://eval.in/90720

Comment: `Matt J. Smith` `Ronald O'Brien` `José Enrique` `FirstName MaidenName MarriedName`

Comment: Thanks and modifying your regex a little would satisfy case for multiple names but not with special characters ^[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)+$

Comment: @SamSullivan yes I am aware of the many other name possibilities, however I answered the question exactly as requested by the OP. - **" All I want to be able to do is allow names like "FirstName MiddleName" having only one space chracter at a time and not at the start of the name."**

Comment: The problem is that both your and mine is not working in prestashop. It is always returning 0

Comment: Thanks I just finished testing another tweaked version of your regex which worked. I will try the one in answer as well. I used this preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]+(\s?[A-Za-z]+)*$/', $name); which obviously is not intended to match dots and quotes

Comment: btw thanks also for linking me to regex101. Previously I was using regexpal which is not as good as regex101

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I used to use regexpal also, but now like regex101 much better. Thanks for accepting as answer.  Good luck.  :)

Comment: Fair enough @MElliott, downvote removed. And yes, +1 for regex101 over regexpal.